# Why doesn't Delphi 7 allow a TList of Extended type

Tags: delphi, casting, tlist

I've created several simple lists (and integer list and color list) yet when I try to make an "extended" list it says invalid typecast even though I've used similar typecasting for the prior 2 lists (it throws the error wherever I use the Extended() typecast).

```
Type
  TAExtList = Class(TObject)
  Private
    FList: TList;
    Procedure SetExt(Index: Integer; Value: Extended);
    Function GetCnt: Integer;
    Function GetExt(Index: Integer): Extended;
  Public
    Constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    Function Add(Value: Extended): Integer;
    Function Insert(Index: Integer; Value: Extended): Integer;
    Procedure Delete(Index: Integer);
    Procedure Clear;
    Function IndexOf(Value: Extended): Integer;
    Property Count: Integer Read GetCnt;
    Property Extendeds[Index: Integer]: Extended Read GetExt Write SetExt; Default;
  End;

Function TAExtList.Add(Value: Extended): Integer;
Begin
  Result := FList.Add(Pointer(Value));
End;
```

Comment: The error message tells you why surely

Comment: What you are looking for is a dynamic array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons. First, as MBo already wrote in his answer, an `Extended` is 10 bytes in size, so it doesn't fit in the 32 bits (4 bytes) of a `Pointer`.

*Another reason is that in Delphi, direct hard casts to floating point types are not allowed, because too many C programmers expected the cast to do a conversion, instead of just a reinterpretation of the bytes of the Extended (or other floating point type). Although the sizes would match, casting to `Single` is not allowed either. Very early versions of Delphi did actually allow these casts, if I remember correctly (or was that Turbo Pascal?).*

But you can still create your `TExtendedList`, if you use **pointers** to `Extended` (after all, a `TList` stores pointers):

```
type
  PExtended = ^Extended;

function TExtendedList.Add(const E: Extended): Integer;
var
  P: PExtended;
begin
  New(P);       // allocate an Extended on the heap and "return" a pointer to it
  P^ := E;      // store the parameter on the heap
  inherited Add(P); // add the pointer to the list
end;
```

But this means that your `TList` now contains ***pointers*** to `Extended`s that are allocated on the heap. So removing or changing requires you to use

```
Dispose(P);
```

at the appropriate places (e.g. in `Delete()`, `Remove()`, `Extract()`, `Clear`, etc. and the destructor). Each of the allocated `Extended`s must be disposed of at the right time.

Retrieving is similar:

```
function TExtendedList.GetExt(Index: Integer): Extended;
var
  P: PExtended;
begin
  P := inherited Items[Index]; 
  Result := P^;
  // or short form: Result := PExtended(inherited Items[Index])^;
end;

procedure TExtendedList.SetExt(Index: Integer; Value: Extended);
var
  P: PExtended;
begin
  P := inherited Items[Index];
  P^ := Value;
  // or short form: PExtended(inherited Items[Index])^ := Value;
end;

procedure TExtendedList.Delete(Index: Integer);
begin
  Dispose(PExtended(inherited Items[Index]));
  inherited Delete(Index);
end;

procedure TExtendedList.Clear;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    Dispose(PExtended(inherited Items[I]));
  inherited Clear;
end;
```

Etc., etc. ...

#### Update

As @kobik said, you could use the virtual Notify function to delete the items that are removed, instead of in each method:

```
procedure TExtendedList.Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification); // declare as override;
begin
  inherited;
  if Action = lnDeleted then
    Dispose(PExtended(Ptr));
end;
```

Comment: `TList` has a virtual `Notify` method. so you can dispose the allocated memory there. e.g. `inherited; if Action = lnDeleted then Dispose(PExtended(Ptr));`

Comment: @kobik: Did Delphi 7's TList have that too? If so, then it would be an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot ;)

Comment: sorry, really new to this so didn't know how to :/  BTW, how do I accept an answer?

Comment: @Skutch It would be a big mistake to use this code. The performance will be poor. Use a dynamic array. And why Extended? It is hard to avoid it being misaligned and again you can expect poor performance.

Comment: @David: did you test it? And dynamic arrays lack the things (like growing, etc.) TList provides.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `SetLength` grows arrays. When I was using pre-generic Delphi I had a set of collection classes that gave `TList` like functionality over the top of arrays. Just like `TList<T>` does. But for performance you want the underlying storage to be a contiguous array. Arrays of pointers to scattered floating point values is bonkers. Nobody needs to test the code to understand that.

Comment: @David: sure that is a possibility, and I had the same. But if you don't really want to reinvent TList, you can use TList as shown.

Answer (score 8):

Both `Integer` and `TColor` have the same size (4 bytes)  as `Pointer` in Delphi 7, that is why explicit casting is possible.

[docWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Typecasts):

> Variable Typecasts
>   You can cast any variable to any type, provided their sizes are the same and you 
>   do not mix integers with reals.

But `Extended` is real, its size is 10 bytes and you cannot cast it to `Pointer`. Moreover, there is no enough place for it.

P.S. Note that fresh Delphi versions contain rather convenient instrument - generics  - just define and create `TList<Extended>`.